# DynamoDB Table: java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to read and write from/to a DynamoDB table while using Spark, but I get a java.io.NotSerializableException:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1459)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.flatMap(RDD.scala:278)
    at com.practice.ops.SBQARandom$.main(SBQARandom.scala:70)
    at com.practice.ops.SBQARandom.main(SBQARandom.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
```

Initially, I got the same exception for AmazonDynamoDBClient and DynamoDB, but I made Serializable subclasses for those. In the case of Table, though, I haven't been table to effectively create a Serializable subclass because the method getTable() in DynamoDB requires Table. I cannot downcast Table to SerializableTable.

Below, you can see the code that causes the exception:

```
val data: RDD[(String, String)] = for {
    item <- getAllData(day1, day2)
    text <- item.text
    if (index.getId(item.id) == "null")
    id <- item.id
} yield (id, text)
```

And getId(String id) is:

```
public String getId(String id) {
    Item item = table.getItem("Id", id);
    return item.toString();
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide code that causes that?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?